# HTTP Requests on Separate Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, http, htmlunit

**Problem:**
I am designing a multi-threaded application in which each thread makes http requests. Multiple threads can be running at once and if multiple http request are in progress at the same time, they don't go through properly. Is there any way to detect when an HTTP request occurs, stop all other threads, and resume all threads when the http request is finished all in a method?

**Additional Info:**
My current solution is to suspend all threads until one is done making requests, then move to the next thread and so on. This basically defeats most of the purpose of having multiple threads in the first place! I know I could go through the entire application and look at every place where an http request might be made and call a method to suspend other threads, but this would be very tedious. By the way I am using HTMLUnit for most of the http requests.

Comment: Why are you using htmlUnit?

Comment: It has some features for HTML screen scraping that I need.

Comment: Are you sharing a webclient amongst threads or creating a new one per threads?

Comment: No I am creating a new one in each thread.

Comment: have you tried JSoup?

Comment: It seems to me that you need an extra layer to control the traffic among these bunch of threads. You can create a "Thread Manager" and exchange information via signals. Imagine a traffic officer (your thread manager) controlling a busy intersection.

Comment: The only issue here is that you said "they don't go through properly" and everybody is trying to guess what that means. Start by explaining yourself, give code examples, the output you get and the expected one... you know... information :)